# Refused to apply style from [Link] because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

**Error Message:**

jquery.dataTables.min.js:23 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at Ha (jquery.dataTables.min.js:23)
    at HTMLTableRowElement. (jquery.dataTables.min.js:16)
    at jquery-1.12.4.js:142
    at Function.map (jquery-1.12.4.js:484)
    at jQuery.fn.init.map (jquery-1.12.4.js:141)
    at ma (jquery.dataTables.min.js:16)
    at e (jquery.dataTables.min.js:92)
    at HTMLTableElement. (jquery.dataTables.min.js:92)
    at Function.each (jquery-1.12.4.js:370)
    at jQuery.fn.init.each (jquery-1.12.4.js:137)

(index):1 Refused to apply style from 'https://databasetable-net.000webhostapp.com/media/css/site-examples.css?_=19472395a2969da78c8a4c707e72123a' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

**Code:** 
Ironically, this same code on Codepen works with no error.

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <title>DataTables example</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/media/images/favicon.png">
    <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS 2.0" href="http://www.datatables.net/rss.xml">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/media/css/site-examples.css?_=19472395a2969da78c8a4c707e72123a">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <style class="init"> </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/media/js/site.js?_=7a5408ceb64d5d41e4b1bfb3712796ab"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/media/js/dynamic.php?comments-page=examples%2Fdata_sources%2Fdom.html" async></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../resources/demo.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" class="init"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function () {
    console.log("Jquery ready");
      $('#example').dataTable( {
      });
});     
  </script>
</head>

<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
<thead>
   <tr>
      <th>
         <a class="column_sort" id="id" href="?order=id&sort=<?php echo $sort; ?>">
            ID</a>
      </th>
      <th><a class="column_sort" id="first_name" href="?order=first_name&sort=<?php echo $sort; ?>">First Name
      </a>
      </th>
      <th><a class="column_sort" id="last_name" href="?order=last_name&sort=<?php echo $sort; ?>">Last Name
         </a>
      </th>
      <th><a class="column_sort" id="position" href="?order=position&sort=<?php echo $sort; ?>">Position
         </a>
      </th>
      <th class="hidden-xs"><a class="column_sort" id="date" href="?order=date&sort=<?php echo $sort; ?>">Date
         </a>
      </th>
      <th class="hidden-xs">
         <a class="column_sort" id="updated" href="?order=updated&sort=<?php echo $sort; ?>">
            Updated</a>
      </th>
      <th>Action</th>
</thead>
</tr>
```

**Possibly solutions:** I tried many but here were some:

Add datatype:json (but I am not using Ajax, but I tried using it anyway under Jquery with no effect)

Add 
Header always set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
 (not exactly sure where to put this but tried many places and did not seem to work)

Changed application/javascript from text/javascript (but did nothing)

I am unable to post comments yet, so I was told to make a new topic based upon my problem The ironic part is that this same code works on CodePen.

Comment: could you show all your `<style>` tags? The error appears to be an issue with a stylesheet import. Are you importing a .html file instead of a .css file like you are with one of your `<script>` imports?

Comment: ok. i posted my entire website code on bottom of my post via edit. I dont really think I used <style> tags so I just posted everything. thanks.

Comment: I got my style sheets from the plug in website by looking at the view page source: https://datatables.net/examples/styling/display.html   It worked for them and on my CodePen: https://codepen.io/ScottFSchmidt/pen/eMzdpO

Comment: Can you copy/paste the exact error message from the javascript console so we can see which line its coming from?

Comment: ok. i pasted two errors word for word. they look like the main 2. Good idea, thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra line in the header that is causing the error.

this line:

```
 <style type="text/css" class="init"> </style>
```

Is invalid.  Remove the `type="text/.css"` part

---

### ** EDIT **

After you pasted the URL for the site in an edit, I was able to visit the site and identify the errors.

You have to upload the following files to your web site as well:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

- demo.js
- site-examples.css
- dynamic.php
- demo.js

.

**Also looks like your missing a critical element for the Datatables JS script**.

```
    (index):22 js ready
    (index):24 Jquery ready
    jquery.dataTables.min.js:23 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
        at Ha (jquery.dataTables.min.js:23)
        at HTMLTableRowElement. (jquery.dataTables.min.js:16)
        at jquery-1.12.4.js:142
        at Function.map (jquery-1.12.4.js:484)
        at jQuery.fn.init.map (jquery-1.12.4.js:141)
        at ma (jquery.dataTables.min.js:16)
        at e (jquery.dataTables.min.js:92)
        at HTMLTableElement. (jquery.dataTables.min.js:92)
        at Function.each (jquery-1.12.4.js:370)
        at jQuery.fn.init.each (jquery-1.12.4.js:137)
```

---

### EDIT

You have to specify the full URL to the above mentioned javascript/css files

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  <title>DataTables example</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="https://datatables.net/media/images/favicon.png">
  
  <!-- add full URL here -->
  <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS 2.0" href="http://www.datatables.net/rss.xml">
  
  <!-- add full URL here -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://datatables.net/media/css/site-examples.css?_=19472395a2969da78c8a4c707e72123a">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
  <style class="init">

  </style>
  
  <!-- add full URL here -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://datatables.net/media/js/site.js?_=7a5408ceb64d5d41e4b1bfb3712796ab"></script>
  
  <!-- add full URL here -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://datatables.net/media/js/dynamic.php?comments-page=examples%2Fdata_sources%2Fdom.html" async></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  
  <!-- add full URL here -->
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://datatables.net/examples/../resources/demo.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" class="init"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      console.log("Jquery ready");
      $('#example').dataTable({ });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <a class="column_sort" id="id" href="?order=id&sort=<?php echo $sort; ?>">
            ID</a>
      </th>
      <th><a class="column_sort" id="first_name" href="?order=first_name&sort=<?php echo $sort; ?>">First Name
      </a>
      </th>
      <th><a class="column_sort" id="last_name" href="?order=last_name&sort=<?php echo $sort; ?>">Last Name
         </a>
      </th>
      <th><a class="column_sort" id="position" href="?order=position&sort=<?php echo $sort; ?>">Position
         </a>
      </th>
      <th class="hidden-xs"><a class="column_sort" id="date" href="?order=date&sort=<?php echo $sort; ?>">Date
         </a>
      </th>
      <th class="hidden-xs">
        <a class="column_sort" id="updated" href="?order=updated&sort=<?php echo $sort; ?>">
            Updated</a>
      </th>
     
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
       <td>System Architect</td>
       <td>Edinburgh</td>
       <td>61</td>
       <td>2011/04/25</td>
       <td>$320,800</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Garrett Winters</td>
       <td>Accountant</td>
       <td>Tokyo</td>
       <td>63</td>
       <td>2011/07/25</td>
       <td>$170,750</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Ashton Cox</td>
       <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
       <td>San Francisco</td>
       <td>66</td>
       <td>2009/01/12</td>
       <td>$86,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
       <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
       <td>Edinburgh</td>
       <td>22</td>
       <td>2012/03/29</td>
       <td>$433,060</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Airi Satou</td>
       <td>Accountant</td>
       <td>Tokyo</td>
       <td>33</td>
       <td>2008/11/28</td>
       <td>$162,700</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
       <td>Integration Specialist</td>
       <td>New York</td>
       <td>61</td>
       <td>2012/12/02</td>
       <td>$372,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
       <td>Sales Assistant</td>
       <td>San Francisco</td>
       <td>59</td>
       <td>2012/08/06</td>
       <td>$137,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
       <td>Integration Specialist</td>
       <td>Tokyo</td>
       <td>55</td>
       <td>2010/10/14</td>
       <td>$327,900</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
       <td>Javascript Developer</td>
       <td>San Francisco</td>
       <td>39</td>
       <td>2009/09/15</td>
       <td>$205,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Sonya Frost</td>
       <td>Software Engineer</td>
       <td>Edinburgh</td>
       <td>23</td>
       <td>2008/12/13</td>
       <td>$103,600</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Jena Gaines</td>
       <td>Office Manager</td>
       <td>London</td>
       <td>30</td>
       <td>2008/12/19</td>
       <td>$90,560</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
       <td>Support Lead</td>
       <td>Edinburgh</td>
       <td>22</td>
       <td>2013/03/03</td>
       <td>$342,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Charde Marshall</td>
       <td>Regional Director</td>
       <td>San Francisco</td>
       <td>36</td>
       <td>2008/10/16</td>
       <td>$470,600</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
       <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
       <td>London</td>
       <td>43</td>
       <td>2012/12/18</td>
       <td>$313,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
       <td>Regional Director</td>
       <td>London</td>
       <td>19</td>
       <td>2010/03/17</td>
       <td>$385,750</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Michael Silva</td>
       <td>Marketing Designer</td>
       <td>London</td>
       <td>66</td>
       <td>2012/11/27</td>
       <td>$198,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Paul Byrd</td>
       <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
       <td>New York</td>
       <td>64</td>
       <td>2010/06/09</td>
       <td>$725,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Gloria Little</td>
       <td>Systems Administrator</td>
       <td>New York</td>
       <td>59</td>
       <td>2009/04/10</td>
       <td>$237,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Bradley Greer</td>
       <td>Software Engineer</td>
       <td>London</td>
       <td>41</td>
       <td>2012/10/13</td>
       <td>$132,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Dai Rios</td>
       <td>Personnel Lead</td>
       <td>Edinburgh</td>
       <td>35</td>
       <td>2012/09/26</td>
       <td>$217,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
       <td>Development Lead</td>
       <td>New York</td>
       <td>30</td>
       <td>2011/09/03</td>
       <td>$345,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Yuri Berry</td>
       <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
       <td>New York</td>
       <td>40</td>
       <td>2009/06/25</td>
       <td>$675,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Caesar Vance</td>
       <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
       <td>New York</td>
       <td>21</td>
       <td>2011/12/12</td>
       <td>$106,450</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Doris Wilder</td>
       <td>Sales Assistant</td>
       <td>Sidney</td>
       <td>23</td>
       <td>2010/09/20</td>
       <td>$85,600</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
       <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
       <td>London</td>
       <td>47</td>
       <td>2009/10/09</td>
       <td>$1,200,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
       <td>Developer</td>
       <td>Edinburgh</td>
       <td>42</td>
       <td>2010/12/22</td>
       <td>$92,575</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
       <td>Regional Director</td>
       <td>Singapore</td>
       <td>28</td>
       <td>2010/11/14</td>
       <td>$357,650</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
       <td>Software Engineer</td>
       <td>San Francisco</td>
       <td>28</td>
       <td>2011/06/07</td>
       <td>$206,850</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Fiona Green</td>
       <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
       <td>San Francisco</td>
       <td>48</td>
       <td>2010/03/11</td>
       <td>$850,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Shou Itou</td>
       <td>Regional Marketing</td>
       <td>Tokyo</td>
       <td>20</td>
       <td>2011/08/14</td>
       <td>$163,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Michelle House</td>
       <td>Integration Specialist</td>
       <td>Sidney</td>
       <td>37</td>
       <td>2011/06/02</td>
       <td>$95,400</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Suki Burks</td>
       <td>Developer</td>
       <td>London</td>
       <td>53</td>
       <td>2009/10/22</td>
       <td>$114,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
       <td>Technical Author</td>
       <td>London</td>
       <td>27</td>
       <td>2011/05/07</td>
       <td>$145,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
       <td>Team Leader</td>
       <td>San Francisco</td>
       <td>22</td>
       <td>2008/10/26</td>
       <td>$235,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Martena Mccray</td>
       <td>Post-Sales support</td>
       <td>Edinburgh</td>
       <td>46</td>
       <td>2011/03/09</td>
       <td>$324,050</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Unity Butler</td>
       <td>Marketing Designer</td>
       <td>San Francisco</td>
       <td>47</td>
       <td>2009/12/09</td>
       <td>$85,675</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
       <td>Office Manager</td>
       <td>San Francisco</td>
       <td>51</td>
       <td>2008/12/16</td>
       <td>$164,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
       <td>Secretary</td>
       <td>San Francisco</td>
       <td>41</td>
       <td>2010/02/12</td>
       <td>$109,850</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
       <td>Financial Controller</td>
       <td>San Francisco</td>
       <td>62</td>
       <td>2009/02/14</td>
       <td>$452,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
       <td>Office Manager</td>
       <td>London</td>
       <td>37</td>
       <td>2008/12/11</td>
       <td>$136,200</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
       <td>Director</td>
       <td>New York</td>
       <td>65</td>
       <td>2008/09/26</td>
       <td>$645,750</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Olivia Liang</td>
       <td>Support Engineer</td>
       <td>Singapore</td>
       <td>64</td>
       <td>2011/02/03</td>
       <td>$234,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Bruno Nash</td>
       <td>Software Engineer</td>
       <td>London</td>
       <td>38</td>
       <td>2011/05/03</td>
       <td>$163,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Sakura Yamamoto</td>
       <td>Support Engineer</td>
       <td>Tokyo</td>
       <td>37</td>
       <td>2009/08/19</td>
       <td>$139,575</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Thor Walton</td>
       <td>Developer</td>
       <td>New York</td>
       <td>61</td>
       <td>2013/08/11</td>
       <td>$98,540</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Finn Camacho</td>
       <td>Support Engineer</td>
       <td>San Francisco</td>
       <td>47</td>
       <td>2009/07/07</td>
       <td>$87,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Serge Baldwin</td>
       <td>Data Coordinator</td>
       <td>Singapore</td>
       <td>64</td>
       <td>2012/04/09</td>
       <td>$138,575</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
       <td>Software Engineer</td>
       <td>New York</td>
       <td>63</td>
       <td>2010/01/04</td>
       <td>$125,250</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
       <td>Software Engineer</td>
       <td>San Francisco</td>
       <td>56</td>
       <td>2012/06/01</td>
       <td>$115,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
       <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
       <td>Edinburgh</td>
       <td>43</td>
       <td>2013/02/01</td>
       <td>$75,650</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Cara Stevens</td>
       <td>Sales Assistant</td>
       <td>New York</td>
       <td>46</td>
       <td>2011/12/06</td>
       <td>$145,600</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Hermione Butler</td>
       <td>Regional Director</td>
       <td>London</td>
       <td>47</td>
       <td>2011/03/21</td>
       <td>$356,250</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Lael Greer</td>
       <td>Systems Administrator</td>
       <td>London</td>
       <td>21</td>
       <td>2009/02/27</td>
       <td>$103,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Jonas Alexander</td>
       <td>Developer</td>
       <td>San Francisco</td>
       <td>30</td>
       <td>2010/07/14</td>
       <td>$86,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Shad Decker</td>
       <td>Regional Director</td>
       <td>Edinburgh</td>
       <td>51</td>
       <td>2008/11/13</td>
       <td>$183,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Michael Bruce</td>
       <td>Javascript Developer</td>
       <td>Singapore</td>
       <td>29</td>
       <td>2011/06/27</td>
       <td>$183,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Donna Snider</td>
       <td>Customer Support</td>
       <td>New York</td>
       <td>27</td>
       <td>2011/01/25</td>
       <td>$112,000</td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
          </table>
```

Comment: If that doesnt do it, then you have to configure the Strict MIME type checking on your http server. The exact procedure varies depending on what kind of server you're running

Comment: Ok thanks for idea. It did not seem to work. I am going to rebuild the site one line at a time and see when it breaks,  I suppose. I wonder if my order of scripts is in wrong order because half of it works while half does not.

Comment: You could look at the javascript console to determine where the error is..  google  'how to show javascript console'  and you'll find an answer for your browser most likely

Comment: Interesting. So far I was able to cut off a lot of errors... I think I only have one error left.

Comment: jquery.dataTables.min.js:23 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
        at Ha (jquery.dataTables.min.js:23)                 
     Well Line 23 is This. I will googe the last error.                                                                                         $(document).ready( function () {
    console.log("Jquery ready");
      $('#example').dataTable( {
      
        } );
});

Comment: I was able to solve the rest of the errors after seeing your post. I guess I will give you credit for the answer as without it, I would not have solved. Thanks! FYI: For future reference to any readers I had to add ajax to my Jquery:$(document).ready( function () {
    console.log("Jquery ready");
      $('#example').dataTable( {
        "ajax": "data.json"
        });
});

Comment: it works. I did get this warning though. If I cannot figure out what it means I will make a different topic.  "DataTables warning: table id=example - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7"

Comment: you need to have a table `<table id="example">`  somewhere on the page i believe..

Comment: I used #example for the id as used in the databasetable.net example. The code works, but not all the way. As of right now, the pagination is the only thing not working

Comment: Thanks, making a HTML datatable is achieved now, just making a server-side one now (which is much harder). This link  seems what I have to do. I may just make a separate topic sometime this week.https://editor.datatables.net/manual/php/getting-started#Basic-initialisation

Comment: nah, you just keep what you have and convert your mysql output into a json array with json_encode n that it

Comment: not really... well.. it could .   whatz the usr case?

Comment: Got the datatables editor.php file-package uploaded today. just got this error now:  Failed opening 'Editor-PHP-1.7.3.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') .  Reading articles on it now. Think once I fix this everything else happens.

Comment: Does the file Editor-PHP-1.7.3.php exist on your filesystem?

Comment: If the file was not uploaded correctly 19 days ago, it is now. I got the issue resolved sorta. At least from the file standpoint but decided to try out ssp.class.php first before Editor. The issue may have been extracting the zip-file but I cannot remember from a few weeks ago.